# How to bind references of two objects?

Tags: java, object, reference

If I have 2 Objects

```
Foo foo;
Foo bar = foo;
```

they both point initially to null.

If foo get's initialized

```
foo = new Foo();
```

bar references to null, but I want it
to be bind to foo.

So every change of the foo reference
effects the bar reference to be the same.

**Is there a way to automatically
let bar point to the same address as
foo,**

**even if it changes or do I have
to call it manually ?**

```
foo = new Foo();
bar = foo;
```

Comment: "they should both point to foo but bar still points to null." - no, they shouldn't.

Comment: I want them to point to the same reference

Comment: @jam You can't. They're both references, so they point to objects. You need to design around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a workaround by creating something like a pointer class.

```
class Pointer <T> {
  T target = null;
  Pointer(T target){
    this.target = target;
  }
  static Pointer nullPointer(){
    return new Pointer(null);
  }
  public void setTarget(T target){
    this.target = target;
  }
  public T getTarget(){
    return target;
  }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
Pointer<Foo> foo = Pointer.nullPointer(); //target=null
Pointer<Foo> bar = foo;           //bar now also "points" to null
foo.setTarget(new Foo()); //now BOTH have the new object as the target
```

Answer (score 1):

Both `foo` and `bar` are not really objects, but references to objects.

In your initial declaration, you are setting both to undefined, or more accurately `foo` is **undefined**, and you are setting `bar` to the same value. However, even if you had initialised `foo`, the answer would be the same.

When you set the value of `foo` to a new object (`new Foo`), you are still leaving `bar` undefined.

So the answer is, yes, you have to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Java is Pass-by-value, not pass-by-reference. The reference of bar should not be the same of foo